# what are the best java development utility tools?

Tags: java, debugging

I would like to know what are the best tools to have in hand for java development. Especially during web developments & debugging? what are the tools most used by the elite league developers apart from the IDEs of their choice.

Thanks for the kind suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For web development? I don't do much in that regard, but when I have to I find Firefox + firebug (and maybe tamper data) extremely useful. Though chrome's dev tools have gotten quite good too.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Debugger works for me and I totally agree with @Voo with the Firefox/Firebug pack. You also need some tools for performance  monitoring and profiling like [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html). Great tool for diagnosing when OutOfMemoryError arises.

If you're building/consuming Web Services, [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a must; and [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) is great for static code analysis. There are several tools according to your needs and context.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) as well.  I find this proxy tool really handy for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[JUnit](http://www.junit.org/), [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), and [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) should be part of your toolkit.